# IdentityServer4: Getting 401 error before expiration time

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've configured Identity Server with my ASP.NET Core API. I'm using this as an identity provider with external service. For easiness I've set AccessTokenLifetime to 1 year. It works great with the newly issued token. But at some time (between 1 hour - 24 hour) it gives 401 error. I checked the exp claim (using jwt.io), it has still one year of validation time. Below is my code

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfiguration.Clients)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfiguration.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityConfiguration.ApiResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityConfiguration.ApiScopes)
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

And my client

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "clientId",
                    ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("mysecret".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedScopes = { "Api.read" },
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600 * 24 * 365 // 1 year
                },
            };
```

Any idea why the 401 error occurs before expiration time and why access token works fine for few time (1 hour - 24 hour)? Does AccessTokenLifetime control token expiration?

Comment: Hi @Munesh Kumar, did all the configuration here? Did you set any refresh token settings or not?